# Splitting a data frame into training and testing sets in R

Tags: r, syntax-error, training-data

I have the following data.frame:

```
>str(customerduration_data)

Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   4495 obs. of  4 variables:

$ monthofgateOUT    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "8"<"9"<"10"<"11": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ dayofgateOUT      : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "Monday"<"Tuesday"<..: 4 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 ...

$ timeofgateOUT     : Ord.factor w/ 20 levels "3"<"4"<"5"<"6"<..: 13 4 2 3 3 11 15 10 13 14 ...

$ durationCUST_hours: num  95.63 5.73 10.73 10.2 14.4 .
```

I want to split this data into a training and a test set, using the following command:

```
install.packages("caTools")

library (caTools)

set.seed(6)

customerduration_data$spl=sample.split(customerduration_data,SplitRatio=0.7)
```

However, after running the above command the following error occurs:

```
>Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, spl, value = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 4495
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please provide code to make reproducible data

Comment: >install.packages("caTools")
>library (caTools)

>customerduration_data<- mydata1 %>%
  select(monthofgateOUT, dayofgateOUT, timeofgateOUT, durationCUST_hours
         ) %>%
  mutate(durationCUST_hours=as.numeric(durationCUST_hours)
  )

> set.seed(6)
> customerduration_data$spl=sample.split(customerduration_data,SplitRatio=0.7)

Comment: please add that `sample.split` is from `library(caTools)`. From the help of the function: `Split data from vector Y into two sets in predefined ratio while preserving relative ratios of different labels in Y. `. You are giving it a data frame. Hence the error.

Comment: I did add library (caTools) before the code to split the data...

Comment: If you're trying to split your data frame into two random chunks of 30% and 70% of your data I'd just use base R: `df$spl <- sample(c(rep("Test", floor(0.7*4495)), rep("Train", 4495-floor(0.7*4495))), replace = F)`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use **base R** which results in a quicker option (3.4 x according to `microbenchmark`) and requires no additional packages:

```
df$spl <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, floor(0.7*4495)), rep(FALSE, 4495-floor(0.7*4495))), replace = F)
```

Splitting this into datasets as:

```
df$spl <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, floor(0.7*4495)), rep(FALSE, 4495-floor(0.7*4495))), replace = F)
test_data  <- df[df[,'spl'] %in% TRUE, ]
train_data <- df[df[,'spl'] %in% FALSE, ]
```

Comment: My test gives an even greater seep-up, 4.6. (Windows 7/R 3.5.0).

Comment: You don't need to compare to `TRUE`, just `df[,'spl']` will do it. And `!df[,'spl']` for the `FALSE` part.

Answer (score 1):

The function `sample.split` expects a vector. Here a simple way to achieve that:

```
library(caTools)
customerduration_data$spl <- sample.split(seq_len(nrow(customerduration_data)), 
                                          SplitRatio = 0.7)
```

Comment: Thank you!

When I tried the following I got another error:
> vars <- c("monthofgateOUT", "dayofgateOUT", "timeofgateOUT")

> str(customerduration_data[, c(vars, "durationCUST_hours")])

> train <- subset(customerduration_data, customerduration_data$spl==TRUE)

> test <- subset(customerduration_data, customerduration_data$spl==FALSE)

> tree_mod <- C5.0(x=train[,vars], y=train$durationCUST_hours)


ERROR: C5.0 models require a factor outcome

Can this be fixed?

Comment: @FleurLolkema You should post this as a separate question. Looking at the output from `str()` above it looks like your outcome is numeric. Normally one would create a new column of type factor with a sensible number of levels, where "sensible" requires domain knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an index column in the original data.frame. If you want to split the df into two sets, `train` and `test`, you can do the following.

```
library(caTools)

set.seed(6)    # make the results reproducible

inx <- sample.split(seq_len(nrow(customerduration_data)), 0.7)
train <- customerduration_data[inx, ]
test <-  customerduration_data[!inx, ]
```

This will *not* create column `spl`. In order to create it, use the answer by @RalfStubner.

**EDIT.**

Another way is to use `sample` with a vector of probabilities.

```
inx2 <- sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 4495, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
```

Testing the three solutions so far, I get the following results.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base_griffinevo = sample(c(rep(TRUE, floor(0.7*4495)), rep(FALSE, 4495-floor(0.7*4495))), replace = F),
  base_Rui = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 4495, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)),
  caTools_Ralf = sample.split(seq_len(nrow(customerduration_data)), 0.7)
)
#Unit: microseconds
#            expr     min       lq      mean  median        uq      max neval
# base_griffinevo 177.072 183.7665  219.3547 195.147  239.6660  523.851   100
#        base_Rui  89.708  93.2225  119.4083 119.666  134.5615  253.389   100
#    caTools_Ralf 838.495 861.4235 1103.0870 926.361 1313.1390 3634.478   100
```

So the simpler, base R way is also the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using the `caret` package, and its `createDataPartition()` function. We'll use the Alzheimer Disease data from the Applied Predictive Modeling package to illustrate creation of test and training data sets.

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
library(caret)
data(AlzheimerDisease)
adData <- data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
# count rows in data frame
nrow(adData)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(diagnosis, p = .75,list=FALSE)
training <- adData[trainIndex,]
testing <- adData[-trainIndex,]
# rows in training data frame
nrow(training)
# rows in testing data frame 
nrow(testing)
```

...and the output:

```
> library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> data(AlzheimerDisease)
> adData <- data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
> # count rows in data frame
> nrow(adData)
[1] 333
> trainIndex <- createDataPartition(diagnosis, p = .75,list=FALSE)
> training <- adData[trainIndex,]
> testing <- adData[-trainIndex,]
> # rows in training data frame
> nrow(training)
[1] 251
> # rows in testing data frame 
> nrow(testing)
[1] 82
>
```